# Reopening Detail View of Recycler View Doesn't Reload Detail View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, detailview

As the app starts up and the user clicks on an item in the List of a RecyclerView, the DetailView is created and everything works like it should. If the user hits the back button to go back to the ListView, it loads fine. Once the user clicks on the item again, my code is not rerun and everything isn't loaded like it should be. The DetailView loads but is the same as the layout file without my code updating it. What I need to know is what I can do to reinitialize everything when the user reopens an Item in the RecyclerView. What methods are called to initialize the items and where can I look for further info? Thanks for any help!

**onCreateViewHolder():**

```
@Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
```

**onBindViewHolder:**

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
            holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mTwoPane) {
                        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                                .commit();
                    } else {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: My code is very long. Which parts would you like me to share?

Comment: Inside onCreateViewHolder, just listener part and also detailsview ?
 
Just an advice, maybe all you need is reinitialize to recycleview in onResume? I could't understand the reason exactly.